# break up the session controller into 3 separate controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a sessions_controller with 3 actions:

```
new
create
destroy
```

but I am thinking that it would be clearer if I created separate controllers for each action, with each controller only doing one thing (sessions#new is less clear to me than login#new):

```
signup
login
logout
```

essentially breaking up the actions at a file level rather than a function level.

are there reasons to do one over the other?

Comment: Have you tried coding these new controllers yet?  I suspect that they will have a large code overlap.  I suppose you could have a parent controller to handle the large code overlap, but I think that would create confusion to people reading the program.

Comment: @TayloredWebSites: haven't got around to trying it out yet, but i imagine that a lot of logic would remain in a helper, and would not be specific to one controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you certainly could break them into separate controllers, I don't think it is necessary and it would make your life a lot harder.

It sounds like you need to utilize [`routes.rb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) to match up requests with the controller. This will keep your session logic grouped while making your paths a little more sensical.

Comment: I do use `routes.rb`, I meant it more in the sense that breaking up the actions into different, distinctively named files would be easier conceptually. edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: But they're still functions of the Session, so it really makes more sense to keep them in the same controller.